# Regex with multiple optional groups

Tags: regex

I've had a search but I can't find a working solution to this. I'm working on a regex for the header formatting for Excel files. These use &-commands for formatting headers and footers, then left, centre and right headers are simply joined together:

(¶18.3.1.39 in the ECMA specification)

```
&L&"Lucida Grande,Standard"&K000000Left top&C&"Lucida Grande,Standard"&K000000Middle top&R&"Lucida Grande,Standard"&K000000Right top
```

All three parts are optional. Based on what I've read about making groups optional I've come up with the following regex (Python style):

```
re.compile(r"""
(?P<left>&L.+?)
(?P<center>&C.+?)
(?P<right>&R.+?)$
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

But it fails with a simple string containing just one part `&Ltest header`. I think I understand the underlying problem – the patterns for missing optional groups affects the other patterns – but not the syntax, or more exactly what happens when a an optional group is missing.

Comment: what's wrong with making all the groups as optional?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @AvinashRaj all groups are optional.

Comment: @sin Python but it shouldn't really matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
^(?:.*?(?P<left>&L.[^&]*))?(?:.*?(?P<center>&C.[^&]*))?(?:.*?(?P<right>&R.[^&]*))?.*$
```

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/pE0tO7/1)

---

Explanation of the `left` group (`center` and `right` are pretty much the same):

```
(?:
    .*? # consume any preceding text
    (?P<left> # then capture...
        &L # "&L" literally
        . # the character after that
        [^&]* # and then everything up to the next "&" character
    )
)? # and make the whole thing optional.
```

---

P.S.: Your pattern didn't make any of the groups optional. You should've put the `?` *after* the group, like `(?P<left>&L.+)?` .

---

### UPDATE

Since the groups aren't supposed to end at the next `&` character, you can try the pattern

```
(?P<left>&L.+?)?(?P<center>&C.+?)?(?P<right>&R.+?)?$
```

instead. All I did was to make all groups optional by adding a `?`, and forcing the pattern to consume the entire string by putting the anchor `$` at the end.

[regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/pE0tO7/2)

**Update**: `(?:&L(?P<left>.+?))?(?:&C(?P<center>.+?))?(?:&R(?P<right>.+?))?$` won't capture the `&L`, `&C` and `&R` bits.

Comment: `&` commands are included in each part so this is too restrictive.

Comment: @CharlieClark: Where do the groups end then?

Comment: With the start of the next group or the end of the text. It's a horrible format.

Comment: Thanks, that's now working (and basically what I had already written except for the trailing $). What's the best way to keep the $L, &C, &R out of the captured group? In a lookahead?

Comment: @CharlieClark: No, you just move it in front of the group, and enclose the whole thing in another non-capturing group. See update.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex that matches `left/center/right` with a series of alternations.
A conditional is used to match the parts irrespective of the order they appear in the line.
This will then make it possible to match 1,2, or 3 of them.

**updated**

Modified to match each section up until the next section (if its there).
Based on the info about conditionals from here -> http://www.rexegg.com/regex-conditionals.html

If its python/PCRE this should work:

```
(?:(?:[^&]|&[\S\s])*?(?:&L(?P<left>(?(left)(?!))(?:[^&]|&[^LCR])*)|&C(?P<center>(?(center)(?!))(?:[^&]|&[^LCR])*)|&R(?P<right>(?(right)(?!))(?:[^&]|&[^LCR])*))){1,3}
```

If its Perl/PCRE, this works:

```
  # (?:(?:[^&]|&[\S\s])*?(?:&L(?<left>(?(<left>)(?!))(?:[^&]|&[^LCR])*)|&C(?<center>(?(<center>)(?!))(?:[^&]|&[^LCR])*)|&R(?<right>(?(<right>)(?!))(?:[^&]|&[^LCR])*))){1,3}

 (?:
      (?: [^&] | & [\S\s] )*?       # Get all possible quoted &&
                                    # even &[LCR] if needed
      (?:                           # Get one of   &L or &C or &R
           &L
           (?<left>                      # (1), Left
                (?(<left>)
                     (?!)                          # Allow only 1 left
                )
                (?: [^&] | & [^LCR] )*        # Get all possible quoted && up to but not &[LCR]
           )
        |  
           &C
           (?<center>                    # (2), Center
                (?(<center>)
                     (?!)                          # Allow only 1 center
                )
                (?: [^&] | & [^LCR] )*
           )
        |  
           &R
           (?<right>                     # (3), Right
                (?(<right>)
                     (?!)                          # Allow only 1 right
                )
                (?: [^&] | & [^LCR] )*
           )
      )
 ){1,3}                        # Do 1 to 3 times
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 132 ) 
&L&"Lucida Grande,Standard"&K000000Left top&C&"Lucida Grande,Standard"&K000000Middle top&R&"Lucida Grande,Standard"&K000000Right top  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 2 , len 41 ) 
&"Lucida Grande,Standard"&K000000Left top  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 45 , len 43 ) 
&"Lucida Grande,Standard"&K000000Middle top  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 90 , len 42 ) 
&"Lucida Grande,Standard"&K000000Right top
```

Comment: This looks like it might work (and how tricky this can be). I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update. I'm currently using the simpler form because it suffices but your solution is extremely instructional because of the subtleties (restricting to only one match, order independent, etc.)