# Regex to match Python docstrings

Tags: python, regex

I would like to parse Python docstrings as follows:

```
Summary of class that is multiple lines.

Parameters
----------
param1 : str
    Param 1 is a param

Returns
-------
value : str

Examples
--------
>>> print()
```

Maps to

```
{
    'base': 'Summary of class that is multiple lines.',
    'params': 'param1 : str\n\tParam 1 is a param',
    'returns': 'value : str',
    'examples': '>>> print()'
}
```

This is pretty straightforward to do with named groups and `re.match.groupdict`, but the issue I am running into is that each of these four groups are optional. There are several questions on here about optional groups, specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711175/regex-with-multiple-optional-groups) seems relevant, but this has nice ending characters to break things up. This docstring can have any characters (currently using `[\s\S]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
^(?P<base>[\s\S]+?)??(?:(?:^|\n\n)Parameters\n-{10}\n(?P<params>[\s\S]*?))?(?:(?:^|\n\n)Returns\n-{7}\n(?P<returns>[\s\S]*?))?(?:(?:^|\n\n)Examples\n-{8}\n(?P<examples>[\s\S]*))?$
```

The code I used to generate this regex:

```py
import re

sep_regex = r"(?:^|\n\n)"
summary_regex  = r"(?P<base>[\s\S]+?)"
param_regex    = rf"(?:{sep_regex}Parameters\n-{{10}}\n(?P<params>[\s\S]*?))"
returns_regex  = rf"(?:{sep_regex}Returns\n-{{7}}\n(?P<returns>[\s\S]*?))"
examples_regex = rf"(?:{sep_regex}Examples\n-{{8}}\n(?P<examples>[\s\S]*))"

combined_regex = rf"^{summary_regex}??{param_regex}?{returns_regex}?{examples_regex}?$"

print(combined_regex)
```

Example:

```py
from pprint import pprint
match = re.search(combined_regex, text)  # text being your example text
pprint(match.groupdict())
# out: {'base': 'Summary of class that is multiple lines.',
# out:  'examples': '>>> print()',
# out:  'params': 'param1 : str\n    Param 1 is a param',
# out:  'returns': 'value : str'}
```

I also tested it with various sections of the docstring dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing your own regular expressions, you can use existing libraries to parse docstrings, whose authors have already done the hard work for you.

I put together an example of this using the [docstring-parser](https://pypi.org/project/docstring-parser/) package. To install this package you need to run this command:

```
pip install docstring-parser
```

Then you can use the following code to parse your docstring:

```py
from docstring_parser import parse

docstring_text = """Summary of class that is multiple lines.

Parameters
----------
param1 : str
    Param 1 is a param

Returns
-------
value : str

Examples
--------
>>> print()
"""

docstring = parse(docstring_text)
docstring_info = {
    "base": docstring.short_description,
    "params": [
        {
            "name": param.arg_name,
            "type": param.type_name,
            "description": param.description,
        }
        for param in docstring.params
    ],
    "returns": {
        "name": docstring.returns.return_name,
        "type": docstring.returns.type_name,
    }
    if docstring.returns
    else {},
    "examples": [{"snippet": example.snippet} for example in docstring.examples],
}
print(docstring_info)
```

This gives the following output (with indentation added for clarity):

```
{
    "base": "Summary of class that is multiple lines.",
    "params": [{"name": "param1", "type": "str", "description": "Param 1 is a param"}],
    "returns": {"name": "value", "type": "str"},
    "examples": [{"snippet": ">>> print()"}],
}
```

Comment: Love that this package exists! Gave you a +1. Unfortunately, for this project we limit our dependencies, and don't have open access to `pip`. However, I will definitely check out the source to understand how they approached this.